# OpenSSL is not available

Tags: macos, openssl, cocoapods

I am trying to add cocoapos for my swift learning but I get the error OpenSSL is not available error message says exactly:ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
OpenSSL is not available. Install OpenSSL and rebuild Ruby (preferred) or use non-HTTPS sources
i guess i played around with ruby ​​and openSSL settings without being sure because ruby ​​2.6. installed and required at least 2.7 for the operation I wanted to do. please help me. I've been trying for 3 days, I can't solve everything. I want to continue learning swift. (I was on firebase in the swift lesson, so cocoapods was needed)

i updated ruby ​​from 2.6 to 3.0.6 but unexpectedly this time i came across this message i tried everything to solve it including deleting ruby ​​and openssl and reinstalling everything